# Image button link does not work on my server

Tags: javascript

I have an image button link that works on my machine and on my old server. We just build a new server on Azure and my image button link will not launch the page. What am I missing in the installation?

```
onclick='javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl00$plchldContents$Menu3$ctl02", "", false, "", "/rootFolder/folder2/somethinghere.aspx", false, false))' type="image"
```

Comment: Does anything helpful appear in the browser console (press F12)?

Comment: The screen refresh.  I run Fiddler to see if it call the somethinghere.aspx ... and nothing.  But on the server that is working I can see the call the aspx page.  I don't see any error anywhere.

Comment: I finally found out why.  It is because of IE set up in Azure server.  I tried it with Chrome and it is working fine.  Thank you for you help!